# How to determine what Microsoft kb is at fault (no https connection to legacy devices) without uninstalling them all?

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2

I just inherited a 2012 r2 server that is having issues accessing legacy https devices. I know it is due to kb articles due to previous experiences.

I don't want to do regression testing, is there a better way? I know it is not possible, but I was hoping it would show all the kb patches that are impacting an application by creating a list of of registry paths accessed by the application and cross referencing it with kb patches.

Ugh.

On the off chance someone would know... Ssl3.dhe 128 is what the issue is. I can access them from Firefox by enabling the old protocols, but ie doesn't work... And i know it is kb related, but can't find the darn article.

Thanks!

Comment: OK, so "KB" stands for "knowledge base" and generally refers to a "knowledge base article".  Microsoft names its patches and updates based on the KB article they're related to, but that doesn't mean their patches and updates are called "KBs."

Comment: What would be the correct term? I know they are security patches, but colloquium  around here is calling them kbs, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3009008) critical SSLv3 vulnerability. I will save you the preaching that you shouldn't use SSLv3 anymore, we all had to support legacy stuff at one point or another.

Comment: Thanks for the assist! Going to see if it works today. Totally agree it is dumb that I need to use legacy stuff.